# Uibinder Widgets

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Is it possible to reuse widgets defined on Uibinder 
example:

```
<g:SuggestBox ui:field='searchBox' />
```

I mean using the same SuggestBox in two different places.
if it is possible how can I do the call or what ever ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't attach the same widget *instance* at two places in the DOM at the same time (because each instance has only one parent field). Do you really want the same instance? If yes, why? (You can of course have multiple instances of the "same" SuggestBox, or multiple instances of the UiBinder widget - wouldn't that be sufficient?)

Answer (score 5):

You can do that, here is an example:

Define a widget you want to reuse:

ExampleLabel.java:

```
package com.example.client;

import import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;

public class ExampleLabel extends Composite {
    interface ExampleLabelBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ExampleLabel>{}
    private static ExampleLabelBinder binder=GWT.create(ExampleLabelBinder.class);
    public ExampleLabel() {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this);
    }
}
```

ExampleLabel.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:Label>Just some text</g:Label>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

To use it you do something like this:

UseExampleLabel.ui.xml:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:myWidgets='urn:import:com.example.client>
<g:FlowPanel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
</g:FlowPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The third line points to the package your widgets is in you want to reuse.

Comment: Yes, this is the way you do it. In short, create your own implementation of SuggestBox with desired functionality, then import it into the UiBinder's XML namespace with a prefix (myWidgets) and then use it as any other GWT widget.

Comment: It means that it is not possible to do this :
<g:FlowPanel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel ui:fields="widget1"></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
    <myWidgets:ExampleLabel ui:field:"widget1"></myWidgets:ExampleLabel>
</g:FlowPanel>

that's what mean ; to use the widget with all its listeners ...

Comment: You can't add the same instance two times, but you could add the handlers in the ExampleLabel.java, when you then add the widgets every instance will have the handlers

Comment: @Issam: In the example above, you wouldn't use `<myWidgets:ExampleLabel ui:field="widget1">`, but instead set the ui:field on the label within the *sub-widget*: `<g:Label ui:field="widget1">`, and also define the listeners there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps !!!
However for the SuggestBox it is simply to define the same MultiWordSuggestOracle object for both before initializing the view
{suggest1= new SuggestBox(oracle);
  suggest2 = new SuggestBox(oracle);
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));}

Comment: @ChrisBoesing, there is an error in the ExampleLabel.ui.xml: The end tag should be `</ui:UiBinder>`, not `</ui:ui:Binder>`. I tried submitting an edit, but it got rejected, I hope you will take the time to fix it, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisBoesing Sorry, but there is still an error. The new end tag is `<ui:Binder>`, it must be exactly the same as the start tag (apart from the slash), i.e. `</ui:UiBinder>`, just like you 'UseExampleLabel.ui.xml' example.